# Find a plane (hyperplane) equidistant from $n$ number of points (more then $2$)

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

Given a set of points $A,B,C,D$ which have $4$ or more coordinates. Is it possible to find a hyperplane equidistant to all the points and how could this plane be defined. Is it possible to get a interval for all the coordinates that describes this hyperplane?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Given any 2 points, any plane that passes through their midpoint would be equidistant to both of these points.

Corollary: Take any hyperplane that contains the midpoint of $AB$ and $CD$.